# Subscribing to events in a separate class

Tags: c#, events, subscription

I am having a bit of trouble subscribing to an event I have created. The event itself is in its own class and I want to be able to subscribe to it from a separate class in a separate project. I am able to subscribe to it from the class in which it is created - but when I try to subscribe from a different class in a different project nothing happens.

Could someone give me a few pointers on how I can work through this at all? I have been all over Google trying to find a solution but to no avail :(.

Comment: Would you please post some of your code?

Comment: Obvious question first:  Is the event public?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example of an event I have created and subscribed to:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.Fooing += () => Console.WriteLine("Foo foo'd");

        foo.PleaseRaiseFoo();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public event Action Fooing;

    protected void OnFooing()
    {
        if (this.Fooing != null)
            this.Fooing();
    }

    public void PleaseRaiseFoo()
    {
        this.OnFooing();
    }
}
```

Hopefully this ought to be able to point you in the right direction.  The main things to check in your code:

- Is your event marked as public?
- Do you ever raise the event? (e.g. `this.Fooing()`)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your sample code with an EventHandler delegate instead of Action (since I couldn't find a non-generic Action delegate in the System namespace)

The code below works just as you'd expect: It outputs "Foo foo'd".

Maybe it's the Action delegate, though I find that somewhat weird.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.Fooing += (object o, EventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine("Foo foo'd");

        foo.PleaseRaiseFoo();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler Fooing;

    protected void OnFooing()
    {
        if (this.Fooing != null)
            this.Fooing(null, null);
    }

    public void PleaseRaiseFoo()
    {
        this.OnFooing();
    }
}
```

Comment: The sample code was posted by Andrew, not the OP. Andrews code should work as is.

Comment: Oh my, I'm terribly sorry - didn't mean to steal the answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
MyInstanceOfMyClass.MyEvent += new EventHandler(MyDelegate);
protected void MyDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You noted that your class is in a different project, can you see the event class (or any other class in that project)? Perhaps you haven't referenced your other project properly.